# Include LOCK_ESCALATION in CREATE Script in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Consider following T-SQL script:

```
USE [DB1];
GO

CREATE TABLE [T1] (
[C1] INT NOT NULL,
[C2] TEXT NOT NULL
);
GO

ALTER TABLE [T1] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO);
GO
```

When I explicitly set LOCK_ESCALATION to DISABLE or AUTO (like in the script above), this information is shown in the script generated using "Script Table as -> CREATE to"

```
USE [DB1]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[T1]    Script Date: 3/26/2015 9:00:24 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [C1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C2] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T1] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [dbo].[T1] TO  SCHEMA OWNER 
GO
```

If I now ALTER that table and set LOCK_ESCALATION to TABLE, like in the following example:

```
USE [DB1];
GO
ALTER TABLE [T1] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE);
GO
```

this line will not be included in the CREATE script generated by "Script Table as -> CREATE to".

```
USE [DB1]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[T1]    Script Date: 3/26/2015 9:14:14 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1](
    [C1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C2] [text] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON [dbo].[T1] TO  SCHEMA OWNER 
GO
```

Is there a way to always include LOCK_ESCALATION in the CREATE scripts?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: I don't think so, since TABLE is the default, you shouldn't need to ALTER something from the default immediately after creation. This is probably this way to avoid having extremely cluttered scripts with all kinds of WITH options / SET statements to blindly state the defaults.

Comment: Lock escalation is almost never set  unless you know in your environment has many, many instances of blocking that you are able to avoid by set lock_escalation to something other then the default setting.. SQL Server in 2012 is very sophisticated  in handling locks and I would not set lock_escalation unless forced.

Comment: I understand your point, guys; I was just hoping there's a way to include all of those defaults in the script, since playing around with Scripting options didn't work for me